# Overloading Output operator for a class template in a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, outputstream

I've this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std ;

#if 0
namespace skg 
{
 template <class T>
  struct Triplet ;
}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t) ;
#endif

namespace skg
{
 template <class T>
  struct Triplet
  {
 //  friend ostream& ::operator<< <> (ostream& os, const Triplet<T>& p_t) ;

   private:
   T x, y, z ;

   public:
   Triplet (const T& p_x, const T& p_y, const T& p_z)
    : x(p_x), y(p_y), z(p_z) { }
  } ;
}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t)
{
 os << '(' << p_t.x << ',' << p_t.y << ',' << p_t.z << ')' ;
 return os ;
}

namespace {
 void printVector()
 {
  typedef skg::Triplet<int> IntTriplet ;

  vector< IntTriplet > vti ;
  vti.push_back (IntTriplet (1, 2, 3)) ;
  vti.push_back (IntTriplet (5, 5, 66)) ;

  copy (vti.begin(), vti.end(), ostream_iterator<IntTriplet> (cout, "\n")) ;
 }
}
int main (void)
{
 printVector() ;
}
```

Compilation fails because compiler could not find any output operator for skg::Triplet. But output operator does exist.

If I move Triplet from skg namespace to global namespace everything works fine. what is wrong here ?

Comment: First, olease try to cleanup the code you attached a bit. Is it necessary to see the parts disabled by preprocessor?
Second, why is the operator not a friend? How is it supposed to access the private members of the triplet class?

Comment: Keep in mind when you do tags, the language should at least be in it :P

Comment: This article explains exactly your problem and how you should use namespaces: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to move your implementation of `operator<<` into the same namespace as your class. It's looking for:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const skg::Triplet<T>& p_t)
```

But won't find it because of a short-coming in argument-dependent look-up (ADL). ADL means that when you call a free function, it'll look for that function in the namespaces of it's arguments. This is the same reason we can do:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

Even though `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` is in the `std` namespace. For your call, those namespaces are `std` and `skg`.

It's going to look in both, not find one in `skg` (since yours is in the global scope), then look in `std`. It will see possibilities (all the normal `operator<<`'s), but none of those match. *Because the code running (the code in `ostream_iterator`) is in the namespace `std`, access to the global namespace is completely gone.*

By placing your operator in the same namespace, ADL works. This is discussed in an article by Herb Sutter: *["A Modest Proposal: Fixing ADL."](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1792.pdf)*. (PDF). In fact, here's a snippet from the article (demonstrating a shortcoming):

```
// Example 2.4
//
// In some library header:
//
namespace N { class C {}; }
int operator+( int i, N::C ) { return i+1; }

// A mainline to exercise it:
//
#include <numeric>
int main() {
    N::C a[10];
    std::accumulate( a, a+10, 0 ); // legal? not specified by the standard
}
```

Same situation you have.

The book *"C++ Coding Standards"* by Sutter and & Alexandrescu has a useful guideline:

> 57. Keep a type and its nonmember function interface in the same namespace.

Follow it and you and ADL will be happy. I recommend this book, and even if you can't get one at least read the PDF I linked above; it contains the relevant information you should need.

---

Note that after you move the operator, you'll need your friend directive (so you can access private variables):

```
template <typename U>
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Triplet<U>& p_t);
```

And ta-da! Fixed.

Comment: Okay, even if the output operator is defined in global namespace and the class in skg namespace, cout << classVariable << endl; would work just fine. Its only the ostream_iterator which is giving the problem. why ?

Comment: @Surya: Clarified. It simply can't look there.